# process.env doesn't show variables outside app.js

Tags: node.js, dotenv

**app.js**

```
    import koa from 'koa';
    import http from 'http';
    import logger from 'koa-logger';
    import koaBody from 'koa-body';
    import dotenv from 'dotenv';
    import dotenvExpand from 'dotenv-expand';

    const config = dotenv.config();

    dotenvExpand(config);

    console.log(process.env); // Here I see all data which are in my .env file

    import { client } from '@pg'; // Inside this file I doesn't see this , but it still after initializing dotenv
```

**@pg = db/connection/index.js**

```
import { Client } from 'pg';

console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL, 'fds'); // here I don't see the same ( all variables from .env file are undefined)

export const client = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL
});
```

if you need additional info, pls let me know. Pay attention on my comments inside of code snippets, it can be helpful

Answer (score 3):

You need to invoke `dotenv` in every file you are calling a `.env` variable.

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { Client } from 'pg';

const config = dotenv.config();

console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL, 'fds');
```

If you want to call `dotenv` in all your app files without calling it every time then you need to require it when you run your app:

```
node -r dotenv/config app.js
```

Comment: When I import 'dotenv' it still undefined , and I run my code by using node_modules/babel-watch/babel-watch.js src/app.js

Comment: or you mean import and then do like dotenv.config() ?

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant. Sorry, updated my answer.

Comment: it is a strange approach in my opinion, but thanks)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You only need to call dotenv.config() one time if you implement it correctly. The correct architecture for a node.js application is to separate the server.ts and app.ts logic into two different files. dotenv should be used inside the app.ts file, and it will work in every other file of your application without re importing it again and again.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use external packages you can just run your script like this :)
I prefer this method.

```
"start": "sh -ac '. ./.env; node index.js'"
```

Comment: While this may work for simple .env files, it does not for `dotenv-expand`.

Comment: dotenv-expand is useless anyway.. if the environment variables are exported  with `export`  in the environment that invokes your script they would be available there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid writing

```
dotenv.config()
```

in every file, you could just simply add this line of code in your `app.js`

```
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, "path/to/.env") });
```